# Serializing the $_SESSION and storing it in a mySQL table

Tags: php, serialization

I'm trying to store my session in a database. I can serialize it and insert it into a TEXT field in a table. I can also pull it back out and 'unserialize' it.  I cannot seem to get it back into my session.

I basically want to grab it from the table, and replace my $_SESSION with it, so all the values of the session will be available again like this $_SESSION['somevalue'].

I serialize it:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    unset($_POST['submit_x'],$_POST['submit_y'],$_POST['submit']);
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
    $serialized_data = serialize($_SESSION);
    setSession($userID,$serialized_data);
}
```

and then save it:

```
 function setSession($userID,$data){
    //is there a row?
    if(getSession($userID)){
        $sql = "UPDATE session_data SET session = '".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."' where user_id = ".$userID;
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT into session_data VALUES('',".$userID.",'".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."')";
    }
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    return $result;
}
```

and then I come to the part where I need to replace my $_SESSION with it.

```
foreach(unserialize($serialized_data) as $key=>$value){
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
```

Can I not put it into a foreach like this? I'm stumped and not really sure which stage I'm going wrong at.

Comment: Have you remembered to `session_start()`?

Comment: You can absolutely use `foreach`--methinks the problem lies elsewhere!

Comment: what's the point in storing session data in the database *this way*? Why don't you use $_SESSION array all the way?

Comment: yes session is all running. Ok good to know i can actually use foreach.

Comment: Your Common Sense, I have my reasons, I want a user to come back days later and pick up where he left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JSON instead of serialize (deep level is guarantee)

$dbstring = json_encode($_REQUEST);
$_REQUEST = json_decode($dbstring, true);